# Animate dynamically generated views using constraints

Tags: ios, swift, animation, constraints, uistackview

I have a few dynamically generated views placed inside a `UIStackView`. I would like to tap on any red view and have it animate to 200 using the width anchor constraint. Having the views dynamically generated and placed within a `UIStackview` is very important.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var arrangedSubviews = [AnyObject]()
        for _ in 0...5 {
                let redView = UIView()
                redView.backgroundColor = .red
                redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                redView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
                redView.layer.borderWidth = 1
                redView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
                arrangedSubviews.append(redView)
        }

        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: arrangedSubviews as! [UIView])
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.height).isActive = true
        view.addSubview(stackView)

        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap)))
    }

    @objc func handleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        let location = gesture.location(in: view)
        print(location)
        for firstViews in view.subviews {
            for secondViews in firstViews.subviews {
                if secondViews.frame.contains(location){
                    secondViews.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    }, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding tap gesture to self.view? Add gesture to redview or add a button in redview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes this

```
secondViews.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
```

into this

```
let widthConstraint = secondViews.constraints.first(where: { $0.firstAttribute == .width })
widthConstraint?.constant = 200
```

And this

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

into this

```
firstViews.layoutIfNeeded()
```